# Redirect from around plugin in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, redirect, plugin, around-plugin

How to redirect from around plugin to another page with an error ?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but this might work for you. The `ManagerInterface` class will set the error message and `response` class will help in redirecting to specific url.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin;

class MyPluginClass
{
    private $response;

    private $messageManager;

    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
    )
    {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function aroundSomeMethod($subject, $proceed, $someThingForTrue){
        if($someThingForTrue){
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('There seems to be some error'));
            $url = 'http://mystoreurl.com';
            $this->response->setRedirect($url);
            $this->response->sendResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check and let u know. Thanks for the response.